# reading a mystery novel again

Tags: meaning, adverbs, redundancy

a. Jane is reading a mystery novel **again**.

b. Jane is reading **another** mystery novel **again**.

c. Jane is reading **the same** mystery novel **again**.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct?

Do they make sense?

Which of them have the meaning

1. Jane is reading another mystery novel

?

Which have the meaning

2. Jane is rereading a mystery novel

?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Jane is reading ***a mystery novel again***

The *indefinite article* shows that Jane is reading *some novel,* but the genre is *mystery.* And, this is not the first time she's doing that.

> Jane is reading ***another*** mystery novel ***again***

This looks confusing to me. It could have been better without *again.* Why? Because it seems redundant.

> Jane is reading ***the same*** mystery novel ***again***

...is **loud and clear**. Say: she read *The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo,* and now she's again reading the same.

Comment: Thank you Maulik V. The question now is whether (a) could be used if she were reading a novel for the second time.